# Name this small red plastic bicycle part

Tags: parts

Please help me to identify this part. The pictures show rear wheel.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

UPD: It is more like an adaptor to connect to the bicycle.

Comment: Is it even "a part"? It looks like it's just a piece of decorative trim on the gear mechanism.

Comment: If you open the screw visible in the bottom picture, I believe you can pull away the gear-changing mechanism and the plastic part will stay attached to the hub. It belongs to the pin that is actuated to change gears in the hub.

Comment: OMG oil your chain

Comment: I'd call it the "adjustment indicator" and you view it through a window or viewport.  Setting the cable tension right should result in the indicator (triangle or arrowhead) being between two lines in/on the window.

Comment: Its very unlikely to be a part you can order directly.  More probably you'd need the whole unit.  Or find/buy a donor bike and scavenge parts from it.

Comment: @paparazzo If the chain were oiled people couldn't hear the cool squeaking sound.

Comment: The part in question is a chain rustiness gauge and it is currently red-lined.

Comment: I am quite interested in a real answer if anyone finds it, especially also the official German name!

Answer (score 8):

I believe the plastic part is similar to the one identified by number 21/22 in the diagram below. I don't have a name for it, though. I am also not suggesting that this is the exact model that is on this bike but I believe it is the same principle.

[image]

Comment: Was there a numbered part list for this diagram? It would be a great addition to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

It seems the manufacturer doesn't have a name for it either because it is sold as part of a three-piece set which is named only after the other two parts: https://www.kurbelix.de/sram-s7-nabenschaltung-schaltstift-roehrchen-set
Hence we in our workshop call it "Roter Schniffuz". Schniffuz is a German very generic colloquial term for a small thing.

[image: Three piece set of hub gear equipment: red schniffuz, tube, stick]

(Legal side question: is posting a screenshot from a online shop here OK?)

Comment: Good find - yeah screenshots are fine, you've got a link to the source page, so if the website vanishes or reorganises in the future then later readers will have some information to go on, which is more useful than a dead link.   (useful) screenshots are a good idea.

Comment: @Criggie I am aware of the link rot problem. I was just not sure if the online shop minds for some legal reasons.

Comment: Good point - the shops don't care, they'd prefer to get more customers.  What you've done by answering the question helps the OP now, and the additional info helps a reader in the future.  Keep up the good work !

Answer (score 2):

This red part can be found under the following names:

1. Red fixing socket for SRAM S7 and P5 speed hubs
2. SRAM ClickBox connection Sleeve.

Comment: I believe it is technically called the locating sleeve but that is splitting hairs. :)